# how to sort a dictionary made of another dictionary by 1 of columns?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

im using the face_recognition library in order check the identity of a person. to do this i create a dictionary that contain all the required data, here is the code

```
x = dict_res["nombre"]
y = dict_res["folio"]
w = dict_res["distance"]
dict_res = {"personas": [{"folio": l, "nombre":k, "distance": d} for k, l, d in zip(x, y, w)] }
```

and here is an example of the output

```
{"personas": [{"folio": "4448", "nombre": "XXXX", "distance": 0.439286309668681}, {"folio":
"9882", "nombre": "YYYY", "distance": 0.4389657479811545}, {"folio": "846547", "nombre": "ZZZZ", "distance": 0.4351502844294799}, {"folio": "10724", "nombre": "WWWW",
"distance": 0.42346392138640926}, {"folio": "952921", "nombre": "AAAA", "distance":
0.44672399211588737}, {"folio": "384388", "nombre": "BBBB", "distance":
0.44584145577924805}, {"folio": "101478", "nombre": "CCCC", "distance":
0.43406962478969346}]}
```

now my question here is how can i sort this dictionary by the distance value? 
i have tried converting to pandas dataframe, sorting and then to dictionary again but i get a dataframe with 1 column and a dictionary in every row. i hope you can helpme.

in advance thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let:

```
dic = {"personas": [{"folio": "4448", "nombre": "XXXX", "distance": 0.439286309668681}, {"folio":
"9882", "nombre": "YYYY", "distance": 0.4389657479811545}, {"folio": "846547", "nombre": "ZZZZ", "distance": 0.4351502844294799}, {"folio": "10724", "nombre": "WWWW",
"distance": 0.42346392138640926}, {"folio": "952921", "nombre": "AAAA", "distance":
0.44672399211588737}, {"folio": "384388", "nombre": "BBBB", "distance":
0.44584145577924805}, {"folio": "101478", "nombre": "CCCC", "distance":
0.43406962478969346}]}
```

You can use `sorted` with `lambda`:

```
dic["personas"] = sorted(dic["personas"], key= lambda x: x['distance'])
```

or `sort` with `lambda`:

```
dic["personas"].sort(key= lambda x: x['distance'])
```